# Assign index and values to a Multidimensional Array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to add specific (numeric) indexes to a multidimensional array in jquery and then assign values at those indexes. Each index will itself be an array and the indexes of these sub-arrays will also be dynamically assigned.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Show').click(function(){ 
        var AllItem = new Array();                             
        $("select[name^='Item']").each(function(dropdownumber, selected) {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var toRemove = 'Item[';
            var name1 = name.replace(toRemove,'');
            var CategoryCode = name1.replace(']','');
            alert('item category code = ' + CategoryCode);
            if (!AllItem[CategoryCode]){ 
                //here I want that index 9 is set as an array, but it adds 9 elements , 
                //I need that only one index is added i.e. 9 and its value is array
                AllItem[CategoryCode] = [];
                alert('added='+CategoryCode);
            }

            //length comes out to be 10 
            //but it should be 1 as I have added only one index i.e. 9 & its an array   
            alert('length='+AllItem.length);

            //after this I need to assign values at 9th index of the array like
            // AllItem[9][0] = 2; //the value of the first index of 9th index is 2
            // AllItem[9][1] = 5;
            // AllItem[9][2] = 6;
            // AllItem[9][3] = 9;
```

**UPDATE :**

```
//for adding values at indexes of AllItem  :  AllItem[9][1] = 5;
$(this).find(':selected').each(function(selectedoptionnumber, selected) {

    var SelectedVal = $(selected).val();
    if (SelectedVal > 0) {
        AllItem[CategoryCode][dropdownumber] = SelectedVal;
        alert(' Code = ' + AllItem[CategoryCode][dropdownumber]);
    }
});

<table style="border: 2px solid #97BDC9; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="Item[9]">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0">-Select-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="Show" value="Show Selected Items" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: better to use `objects` here.

Comment: @Mritunjay : how to use objects ? can you please mention the code

Comment: @sqlchild: I cover it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> here I want that index 9 is set as an array, but it adds 9 elements ,
>
> I need that only one index is added i.e. 9 and its value is array

Actually, it doesn't add nine elements, just one. That one element is at index `8` (presumably, not `9` — remember indexes start at `0`); indexes `0-7` *do not have values at all*. This is because JavaScript standard arrays are inherently *sparse* (and [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)). More on this below.

> length comes out to be 10
>
> but it should be 1 as I have added only one index i.e. 9 & its an array

The `length` property isn't defined to be a count of the number of entries in the array. It's defined to be (at least) one greater than the highest array index. Because arrays can have missing entries, the `length` can be more (but not less) than the number of entries in the array.

Now, if you don't need the array-ness of the array object, you could just use a plain object instead. The only difference is that it doesn't have a `length` property, and doesn't have the various array-specific functions (`forEach`, etc.). To do that, just change your

```
var AllItem = new Array();
```

line to

```
var AllItem = {};
```

You can use the `[]` notation with objects as well as arrays (because arrays are just objects, the `[]` notation is an *object* thing, not an *array* thing), so your other code doesn't change

But again, the *only* difference is the `length` property and the various array functions.

---

More on how adding an entry at index 8 doesn't create entries at 0-7:

When you do this:

```
var a = [];
a[8] = "value";
```

All that happens is that entry `8` is set to the value and `a.length` is set to `9`. *Nothing* else is added to the array.

```
console.log(0 in a); // false
console.log(1 in a); // false
...
console.log(7 in a); // false
console.log(8 in a); // true!
```

People sometimes have trouble wrapping their heads around this, but the key to it is in the linked article above: Arrays aren't really arrays at all, they're just objects with a bit of magic thrown in. Array "indexes" are just property names, and array "entries" are just properties. So `a[8] = "value"` creates a property called "8" on the `a` object. It does not create any other properties.

When you *read* the value of a property that doesn't exist (on the object or its prototype), you get back the value `undefined`, but that doesn't mean the property exists, that's just how JavaScript is defined to deal with that situation (reading a property that doesn't exist).

The `in` operator (used above) and `hasOwnProperty` function let you test for whether a property exists *at all* (`in` looks at the ojbect and its prototype(s), `hasOwnProperty` only looks at the object).

---

Re your question below about your updated code, this line may or may not be a problem depending on what other code you have:

```
AllItem[CategoryCode][dropdownumber] = SelectedVal;
```

That's fine **if** you've already put an object or array at `AllItem[CategoryCode]`. If you haven't, it will cause an error.

If you know you've done that, then the line is fine.

If you know you *haven't* done that, then:

```
AllItem[CategoryCode] = [];
AllItem[CategoryCode][dropdownumber] = SelectedVal;
```

If you *may or may not* have done that, then:

```
if (!AllItem[CategoryCode]) {
    AllItem[CategoryCode] = [];
}
AllItem[CategoryCode][dropdownumber] = SelectedVal;
```

*(Or sometimes you'll see this:*

```
(AllItem[CategoryCode] = AllItem[CategoryCode] || [])[dropdownumber] = SelectedVal;
```

*but there's usually no need for that kind of thing, which is hard to read and hard to debug.)*

Comment: sir, please check my update for further assigning values to the AllItem array , is it correct or needs to be modified.

Comment: @sqlchild: I've added to the end to answer your question, but it seems fairly unrelated (normally a question should have *one* question in it). Side note: Please review the edits that Artjom B. and I have made to your question, so you can do that (make it possible to see the code) for yourself in future.

Comment: sir, when I post AllItem to my php file and display it, then it shows it as [object Object] , but I need the whole array in my PHP file and do further processing.

Comment: @sqlchild: That's a separate question. I suggest posting it as a question. Show the JavaScript code 1. Creating `AllItem`, 2. Populating it, and 3. Sending it to the server, as well as the PHP code retrieving and using it.

Comment: if I do alert(AllItem); then also it shows [object Object] , where did its all indexes and values go? isn't it an array whose all values and indexes can be accessed?

Comment: @sqlchild: See comment above.

Comment: sir, i ain't talking about the php file , am just talking about the script i have posted here in my question ......how to write all indexes and values of AllItem array to the browser console using console.log ?

Comment: @sqlchild: If you use `console.log(AllItem);`, you should see its contents on any modern browser: http://jsbin.com/pamen/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/pamen/1/edit).

Comment: am posting the AllItem array to a php file as : $.post('process_items.php' , { 'Item[]' : AllItem} ) , but in the php file when I receive AllItem in the POST array then it shows just - [object Object]

Comment: @sqlchild: **Again**: That is a different question. Post it, with the various things I listed above, and someone can help you (possibly me, but possibly someone else).

Comment: sir, I got the problem, when am using jquery 1.3.2 then I have to stringify AllItem and i receive it , but if use 1.11.1 then I receive it as an array.....is it possible make things work out with 1.3.2 version ?