# Post multidimensional array/object to php file using ajax/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array

I require that in my PHP file I receive AllItem as a multidimensional array instead of a string, so that I can loop it using foreach and do further processing.

```
     $.post("show_items.php", 
         { 'AllItem' : JSON.stringify(AllItem)}, 

             function(msg)
             {  

                  console.log(AllItem);
```

**console output :**

```
    Object {9: Array[2]}
    9: Array[2]
    0: "1"
    1: "4"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
                                alert(msg);
```

**alert output :**

```
string(22) "{\"9\":[\"1\",\"4\"]}"

                            });
```

The method of building AllItem array can be checked out on my previous question:

[Assign index and values to a Multidimensional Array in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103348/assign-index-and-values-to-a-multidimensional-array-in-jquery)

How should I post the AllItem object so that I could receive it as an array in the server file.
Shall I use json_encode in my php file? Right now am receiving it as :

```
$AllItem = $_POST['AllItem'];

echo $AllItem;
```

Comment: i did update my answer, json_decode is not necessary in the php file

Comment: look at your post request, it should contain form data like `AllItem[9][]: 1` and `AllItem[9][]: 4` which is stored in `$_POST` as `array('AllItem' => array(9 => array(1, 4)))`

Comment: how do I check the post request?

Comment: A quick and dirty way is to have an nearly empty index.php which logs `$_POST` to some file via `file_put_content('/tmp/test.txt', print_r($_POST, true));` and has some inline js like `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).on('ready', function() { $.post('index.php', {'AllItem': {'9':[1, 4]}}, function(){alert('done');}); }); </script>`

Comment: @SBH -  do I need to use both jquery files together , as I found out that its a jquery problem

Comment: I did rewrite my answer. Just stick to jquery 1.3.2 if you need it and adopte your php.

Comment: @SBH : I get NULL when I do json_decode twice or once...am sending AllItem after applying JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

Since your bound to jquery 1.3.2 I rewrite my answer:

Keep your javascript unchanged as you did write it in your question.

In your PHP file you right now receive a string as you did write in your alert output.
Depending on how your string looks exactly you need to json-decode it once or twice, but make shure to set the second parameter to `true`:

```
$AllItem = json_decode(json_decode($_POST['AllItem'], true), true);
```

This will give you the associated array.

Comment: I did that but then it displays : "[object Object]"

Comment: still the output it same. "[object Object]"

Comment: I got two php files having the above script , both using different versions of jquery, in one it works and in the other one it is not working...in one it shows the whole AllItem array and in other one it shows only "[object Object]"  , does this means that the jquery version has some glitch?

Comment: I am bound to use the older version jquery file (1.3.2) , but it is not supporting this above script ? what do I do ? I can't replace the new version of jquery file...is it possible to use the older one and make this script work anyhow?

Comment: Sir, I have created a jsfiddle also, please check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/nfunbo2e/9/

Comment: The code in jsfiddle gives the string after stringify but when I post it to server then I don't get back an associative array